# PartialFunction to partially applied function

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do the following:

```
val divide: PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int] = {
    case (x, y) if (y != 0) => x / y
}

val divide42 = (y: Int) => divide((42, y))
```

However:

```
divide42.isDefinedAt(0)
```

---

```
cmd18.sc:1: value isDefinedAt is not a member of Int => Int
val res18 = divide42.isDefinedAt(0)
                     ^Compilation Failed
```

What is the right way to preserve `PartialFunction` functionality when going from `PartialFunction` to partially applied function?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `compose` to preserve the partial nature:

```scala
val divide: PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int] = {
    case (x, y) if (y != 0) => x / y
}

val divide42: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = divide.compose {
  case y: Int => (42, y)  
}

divide42.isDefinedAt(0) // false
```

What you wrote doesn't work because it's actually syntactic sugar for the following:

```scala
val divide42 = new Function1[Int, Int] {
  def apply(y: Int) = divide((42, y))
}
```

The call to `divide` inside `divide42` is an expression that evaluates to `Int` (or throw). There is no way to preserve the fact that `divide` is a partial function with this syntax.

---

Or explicitly write a new partial function like this but more verbose:

```scala
val divide: PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int] = {
    case (x, y) if (y != 0) => x / y
}

val divide42: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case (y: Int) if divide.isDefinedAt((42, y)) => divide((42, y)) 
}

divide42.isDefinedAt(0) // false
```

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov added a bit of comment

Comment: @GaëlJ well put, makes sense to me, tyvm :)

Comment: You're invited to compare yours and mine below.

Answer (score 0):

Help the compiler help you, define your types explicitly:

EDIT: I realized that simply changing the types results in the `y != 0` part of the function not working as intended. `compose` addresses this as already mentioned in another answer (which is correct).

```scala
val divide: PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int] = {
    case (x, y) if y != 0 => x / y
}


// OLD: val divide42: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = (y: Int) => divide((42, y))
// |- Returns true for `isDefinedAt(0)` which is WRONG!!
// |- If someone could explain why this happens (???), please comment :)

val divide42: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = (y: Int) => divide.compose {
    case y: Int => (42, y)
}

divide42.isDefinedAt(0) // False
```

When you define it as you have, the compiler changes the type of `divide42` to `Int => Int` as opposed to `PartialFunction[Int, Int]`:

```scala
// Implicit type, `Int => Int`
val divide42 = (y: Int) => divide((42, y))

// `isDefinedAt` is not defined for `Int => Int`
divide42.isDefinedAt(0) // !! Error !!
```

Comment: `isDefinedAt(0) \\ true ` was wrong indeed. But now we're back to what already was answered 10 hours ago. The original version was kneat but doesn't work as intended. Why?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov that is a good question, one I have as well; doesn't seem intuitive to me, but as currently written, it should work as intended

Comment: It's more of a question "why?" than "what just works". Ascribing the right type seem to be  the step in the right direction. But how make it work? And why `compose` ???

Comment: Your "old" `PartialFunction` is defined for the input 0. It is actually defined for every `Int`. See my answer updated with a comment to help understand why.

Comment: @GaëlJ could you clarify on how `isDefinedAt(0)` is synthesized? That it accepts 0 doesn't make sense still actually

Comment: Think of it this way: a total function is a special case of a partial function defined for all inputs.

Comment: @GaëlJ so it's just like: "expects any integer" and then throws an exception only when `apply` is called because it doesn't match on a case?

Answer (score 0):

The following seem right to me:

```
val divide: PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int] = {
    case (x, y) if (y != 0) => x / y
}

val divide42: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case x if (x != 0) => divide(42, x)
}

divide42.isDefinedAt(0) // false

divide42(6) // 7
```

This both follows the correct definition pattern for `PartialFunction` and suits the definition of a partially applied function

Comment: Drawback of this is that you are repeating the condition (`x != 0`) in both functions. With `compose` you don't need to know at which input the first function is defined.

Comment: @GaëlJ I do not see this as a drawback until you disclose how `compose` overcomes this

Comment: By this definition of `isDefinedAt` for the composed function: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.5/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L271-L274 (you can also look at `def compose` to see it returns a `Combined`.